# How to update individual aurelia-slickgrid column

Tags: aurelia, slickgrid

This is the table i am trying to make. First two columns are filled from get api. The last column, i fetch from another api get call. How do i fill the last column with data.

[image]

```
defineGrid() {
    this.columnDefinitions = [
        { id: "SerialNumber", name: "Serial Number", field: "SerialNumber", sortable: true, filterable: true, minWidth: 100 },
        .......
        .......
        .......
        { id: "Owner", name: "Owner", field: "Owner", sortable: true, filterable: true, minWidth: 100 },
    ];
```

Is there a way in aurelia-slickgrid to update an individual column with values (from a promise let’s say)?
I want to update the Owner column from a separate function that gets the data from backend system. I mean not the way how rest of the data is updated using dataset.bind=“dataset”.

Comment: it's not very clear what you're asking... you need to provide a bit more details/code of what you're trying to achieve. If it's adding/removing columns dynamically, that is demoed in the few examples, if you want to load Filter/Editor collection in then use `collectionAsync`, if it's any other properties then which one? As you can see your question is not clear enough to provide correct answer

Comment: @ghiscoding thanks for the reply. I updated with an image of table. I fill the first two columns from a get api's response data.Now i need to fill the last column from another get api's response data.

Comment: That is still not clear... are you talking about adding a column definition dynamically? If so,  you can see that in [Example 3](https://ghiscoding.github.io/aurelia-slickgrid/#/slickgrid/example3)... or are you talking about filling extra data inside the grid? If it's the data that you need to update, then you have to loop through your entire dataset and update it each item like Example 11. The grid works with only 1 dataset, if you need to merge 2 datasets then it's your decision & you'll have to loop through like I said but I never do that, you should have merged data from backend direcly